# Intern framework - LeadFoot - unable to locate element

Tags: javascript, java, intern, leadfoot

I am writing functional test cases using leadfoot intern framework.
Test Case: Enter the form field and click a button which will open up a bootstrap modal. All i am trying to do is verify the display property of the element present on the modal.

But when i try to find the element by id 'viewBtn' it does not find it and throws:
NoSuchElement: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/e23a975b60188479d599d2
43505ce9cb/element/0.1521919297986265-4/element / {"using":"id","value":"viewBtn
tBtn"}] no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"viewBtn
"}

```
define(function (require){
    var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
    var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');

    registerSuite({
        name:'Test Page',
        'Continue':function(){
            return this.remote
             .get(require.toUrl('http://sdfsdfs'))
             .setFindTimeout(5000)
            .findById('to')
            .click()
            .type('john')
            .end()                      
            .findById('from')
            .click()
            .type('man')            
            .end()          
            .findById('message')
            .click()
            .type('hello')
            .end()          
            .findByCssSelector("[name=formName]").findByClassName('btn')
            .click()
            .end()
            .setFindTimeout(5000)
            .findById('viewBtn')
            .isDisplayed()
            .then(function(text){
                assert.equal(text,'true','Not Displayed');
            })
        }
    });
})
```

;

Why is it throwing error when the id is present in the element. Also i am calling **end** method after every **find** method.?

Comment: May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that frame or iframe before finding the element.

Comment: No html does not have frame or iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may not be searching in the correct context. In the snippet below, there is only one `end` between two finds and the `findById`). This means the context at the point `findById('viewButton')` is called is the element with name "formName" (so that the `findById` is only searching within/under the name="formName" element), because only the `findByClassName` call was ended:

```
.findByCssSelector("[name=formName]").findByClassName('btn')
.click()
.end()
.setFindTimeout(5000)
.findById('viewButton')
```

To search the entire doc (assuming that's the intention), call `end(2)` to end both of the finds.

Also, note that `setFindTimeout` is persistent, so you only need to call it once unless you're changing the value.